# generate a fake KeyEvent

Tags: android

I'd like to know how to generate a fake press button event . The button in cause is a options menu button. Please tell me if this is possible, or sugest other references !

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If it is your own code, frequently it will be simpler to use other techniques. For example, to open the options menu, call `openOptionsMenu()` on your `Activity`.

If it is for some other application's code, you cannot "generate a fake press button event".

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
mBtn.performClick();
```

It calls onClickListner of that button, if it is set by you. And if you want it be a fake click do nothing in the body of `onClickListener()`.